# which books should i refer for embedded systems?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, embedded, c

i am in second year of mechanical engineering and i want to learn about embedded systems and to program them.from where should i start? which books to refer? is it possible to learn it without any coaching? I have completed my c programming course.

Comment: you are a mechanical engineer why you want to build embedded design. But if you really want, then you can go for Mazidi books for 8051, AVR & PIC controllers

Answer (score 3):

1. Pick a microcontroller
2. Google embedded systems and the microcontroller of choice. (There are many that have special book designated for that, but also many that don't)
3. Look into an [evaluation board](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/2) that'll make your life easier and less time consuming to start the project

Maybe Try [sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com)

There are many good microcontrollers to start with

- PIC (microchip)   [PIC Embedded system book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1856177505)
- Arduino [Arduino Embedded system book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449389716)
- MBed (highly recommend it for easy start, easy drag in file programming, and online compiler prepared for you) [Mbed cookbook](http://mbed.org/cookbook/)
- Propller [Propller Embedded system book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449340105)

and much else